# Get all prediction values for each CV in GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, gridsearchcv

I have a time-dependent data set, where I (as an example) am trying to do some hyperparameter tuning on a Lasso regression.

For that I use sklearn's `TimeSeriesSplit` instead of regular Kfold CV, i.e. something like this:

```
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)

model = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=pipeline,
    param_distributions= {"estimator__alpha": np.linspace(0.05, 1, 50)},
    scoring="neg_mean_absolute_percentage_error",
    n_jobs=-1,
    cv=tscv,
    return_train_score=True,
    max_iters=10,
    early_stopping=True,
)

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

With this I get a model, which I can then use for predictions etc. The idea behind that cross validation is based on this:

[image]

However, my issue is that I would actually like to have the predictions from all the test sets from all cv's. And I have no idea how to get that out of the model ?

If I try the `cv_results_` I get the score (from the scoring parameter) for each split and each hyperparameter. But I don't seem to be able to find the prediction values for each value in each test split. And I actually need that for some backtesting. I don't think it would be "fair" to use the final model to predict the previous values. I would imagine there would be some kind of overfitting in that case.

So yeah, is there any way for me to extract the predicted values for each split ?

Comment: could you please elaborate a little bit on your question? my understanding from the first line under the images is: "you want to extend the test set to be all the data like the iter0 will be train:[0,9] test [10,99] (instead of [10,19]) " is that what you want?

Comment: Do you want the predictions from every candidate, or just from the selected/"best" hyperparameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have custom scoring functions in `GridSearchCV`.With that you can predict outputs with the estimator given to the `GridSearchCV` in that particular fold.
from the documentation scoring parameter is

> Strategy to evaluate the performance of the cross-validated model on the test set.

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error
def custom_scorer(clf, X, y):
     y_pred = clf.predict(X)
     # save y_pred somewhere
     return -mean_absolute_percentage_error(y, y_pred)

model = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipeline,
                     scoring=custom_scorer)
```

The input `X` and `y` in the above code came from the test set. `clf` is the given pipeline to the `estimator` parameter.
Obviously your estimator should implement the predict method (should be a valid model in `scikit-learn`). You can add other scorings to the custom one to avoid non-sense scores from the custom function.

Comment: That seems like the way to go. However, just curious. I thought the scoring method was how the estimator optimizes its parameters ? Hence, if you used the one in my example `neg_mean_absolute_percentage_error` it would try to maximize the values (since it's negative). In your example you just do some prediction, and your return is not just one value. Or how does this work ? Does it still use the `neg_mean_absolute_percentage_error` for optimization, and then just use the custom_function as something extra, or...?

Comment: You can compute the `neg_mean_absolute_percentage_error` using its function. The function gets `y_true` and `y_pred` as parameters. Add the function to the `custom_scorer` and you don't need the list of scoring anymore. Actually the `custom_scorer` need to return a floating point value to work properly. I just updated my answer.